# Is there any opensource netty Ldap Encoder / Decoder

Tags: ldap, netty

I wonder if there any Ldap Request decoder and Ldap Response encoder for netty.
As I rather not write a ASN.1 codec using Ber encoding mechanism.

- Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one based on [Apache MINA](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/shared/trunk/asn1/) implemented for [Apache Directory Server](http://directory.apache.org/). If you would like to port it to Netty let me know.

Comment: The mina codec (that I know of) is deeply coupled with Apache DS. In my situation, I need to do away from the storage component. How difficult would it be to port it to netty ? - Thanks

Comment: No, the codec does not depend on ApacheDS, think of this like an LDAP client.

Comment: I am not sure if this apply to building an ldap server, care to point to the actual project code base? Thanks.

Comment: 1. ASN.1 http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/shared/trunk/asn1
2. LDAP codec http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/shared/trunk/ldap/codec

The entire reusable API module can be found at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/shared/trunk

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you would like to write a LDAP codec ?